# Infinite loop (hybridAuth & Heroku)

Tags: loops, heroku, hybridauth

I use hybridAuth in order to connect with facebook, everything works fine with my previous hoster, but when I move to Heroku I get an infinite loop (on /index.php?hauth.start=Facebook&hauth.time=1399730233). Do you have an idea of where the problem stems from? (server configuration?)

Thank you

Comment: I have the same problem. did you resolve it?

Comment: I finally went back to my previous hoster...